# JSoup storing text in a variable

Tags: java, android, jsoup

i'm new in JAVA / Android development.

I made an app to extract text from a HTML class;

```
protected List<String> doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
                    "http://example/test.html").get();

            Elements st1 = doc.select("a[class*=subject_rating_details");

            for (Element element : st1) {
                sgrade[0] = st1.get(0).text();
                sgrade[1] = st1.get(0).text();
                sgrade[2] = st1.get(0).text();
                sgrade[3] = st1.get(0).text();
                sgrade[4] = st1.get(0).text();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<String> pinfo = null;
        return pinfo;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> pinfo) {
        prog.dismiss();
    }
}

List<ListData> varlist = new ArrayList<ListData>();
String sgrade[] = new String[] {};
```

I used JSoup to extract from my webpage different text from the HTML class="subject_rating_details".

But it force closes with the code above.

I can successfully extract it with a single String, example:

```
for (Element element : st1) {
stringname = st1.get(0).text();
stringname = st1.get(1).text();
stringname = st1.get(2).text();
stringname = st1.get(3).text();
stringname = st1.get(4).text();
}
```

But it only stores the last one ( stringname = st1.get(4).text(); )

I've tried also:

```
for (Element element : st1) {
stringname1 = st1.get(0).text();
stringname2 = st1.get(1).text();
stringname3 = st1.get(2).text();
stringname4 = st1.get(3).text();
stringname5 = st1.get(4).text();
}
```

But i need the text from st1 in a single variable.

What can i do?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I want something like this:

String sgrade[] = new String[] {};

```
for (Element element : st1) {
                sgrade[0] = st1.get(0).text();
                sgrade[1] = st1.get(0).text();
                sgrade[2] = st1.get(0).text();
                sgrade[3] = st1.get(0).text();
                sgrade[4] = st1.get(0).text();
```

}

Witch later i could read each text and display it in a TextView:

```
textview1.setText(sgrade[0]); <--/// This would display "Ford"
textview2.setText(sgrade[1]); <--/// This would display "Mustang"
textview3.setText(sgrade[2]); <--/// This would display "2013"

/// HTML ///

...

<p class="subject_rating_details">Ford</p>
<p class="subject_rating_details">Mustang</p>
<p class="subject_rating_details">2013</p>

...

/// HTML ///
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this way. With this you will get value of st1 in single string named stringname.

```
List<String>   stringname =new ArrayList<String>();

  for (Element element : st1) {
stringname.add(st1.get(0).text());
stringname.add(st1.get(1).text());
stringname.add(st1.get(2).text());
stringname.add(st1.get(3).text());
stringname.add(st1.get(4).text());
}
```

Comment: Ok i tested it this way but it does not suits my needs. I want to store in stringname the text from JSoup, but something more as a list wich i can use like:    textview.setText(stringname[0]);    textview2.setText(stringname[1]);

Comment: Ok, then  declare stringname as List<String> and inside for loop add each text value to list.